# Right way to manage many (~200) custom rewrites in NGINX

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Please, help me to solve the problem in the best way.

I'm changing my website structure completely, and there is no way I can use regex with rewrites, because of such urls (~200 urls):

```
from
    mysite.com/a-page-about-something/
to
    mysite.com/completely-different-name-of-a-page-about-something/
```

So, what's the proper way for setting up such a large set of custom redirects?
Is it OK, if NGINX will be "scanning" 200 lines of rewrites every access to the server?

I saw this -- a bit similar question and answer:
[Using nginx rewrite with many individual URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785207/using-nginx-rewrite-with-many-individual-urls)

But, in my case, urls are completely different -- without a part which I can use to "call a function or not to call" ("index.php?", for example)
And, tell me if wrong, using backend (PHP) every call for searching a match is not the best (fastest) solution for my case.

Comment: If you need only full match `location` blocks would be more efficient.

Comment: You mean, more efficient than backend (PHP)? OK, if I will be doing with NGINX, is the best way -- to write separate locations or there are another better techniques? I don't know NGINX very well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it's better to have such application logic inside of your application, so the first solution to have such redirect in your application.

If you really want to have these redirects in nginx, I would recommend to have them is separate file and include into you main server file. Something like that:

```
location /a-page-about-something/ {
    return 301 /completely-different-name-of-a-page-about-something/;
}

location /another-page/ {
    return 301 /second-page/;
}
#... and so on
```

Comment: Yes, after googling and a bit thinking, I've decided to do exactly this way. Already did -- works perfect. Thank you.